# Filter store on combobox selection

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have tried this different ways, but still can't get the filter to work. My ext app lets user to choose a single state from a combobox, and the grid below displays more data on that selected "value"=state.. On select, the combobox fires a function that filters the store of the grid and updates the store...
this is my store for the grid...

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        id: 'OurData',
        pageSize: 20,
        pageNumber: 1,
        remoteSort: true,
        fields: [
    { name: 'States' },
    { name: 'FullName' },
    { name: 'Capital' },
    { name: 'Population' }
    ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'GetState/getS',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'myTable',
               idProperty: 'States',
                totalProperty: '@count'
            }
        }
    });
    store.loadPage(1);
```

this is my combobox

```
xtype: 'combo',
                    id: 'iccombo',
                    scope: this,
                    store: this.Combostore,
                    fieldLabel: 'Short State',
                    displayField: 'States',
                    valueField: 'States',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    queryMode: 'remote',
                    name: 'State',
                    labelWidth: 125,
                    anchor: '95%',
                    listeners: {
                        scope: this,
                        select: this.fireFilter
                    }
```

and this is where the filter should take place...

```
fireFilter: function (value) {

    // Get passed value
    this.selectedC = value.getValue();
    console.log('selectedValue: ' + this.selectedC);

    // Clear existing filters
    this.store.clearFilter(false);

    // Build filter

    var myfilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
        scope: this,
        filterFn: function (item) {
            var fieldNames = item.fields.keys;

            for (var j = 0; j < fieldNames.length; j++) {
                var fieldName = fieldNames[j];
                if (item.data[fieldName] != null) {
                    var stringVal = item.data[fieldName].toString();
                    if (stringVal != null && stringVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
    // Apply filter to store
    this.store.filter(myfilter);
}
```

when I run the code, it display all data in the grid, and on selection of combobox, it still shows the same data..
For some reason, the code never runs through the filterFn... because my console.log doesn't show up
this is what I got in firebug's response

```
_dc     1352902173425
filter  [{"property":null,"value":null}]
limit   20
page    1
start   0
```

as you can clearly see, the selected 'value' is null, but my 'console.log' prints the value selected... I think the way I am getting the passed value and applying the filter is incorrect... can someone please take a look... thanks

UPDATE... I am able to get inside the function and my console.log shows all the fields... but once I get to the last if statement... I get this error

> TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to dbrin's anwser I also can't understand why you are using `remoteSort` but not `remoteFilter`? You may also have a scope issue by using `this`.

Anyway I would recommend you to extend a new combo type so that you are also be able to clear your filter if you have the need to. Here is an extension I have written for my own use. Note that the filtering itself needs to be implemented in the `onSearch` method, which can be either a remote or a local sort.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.FilterCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.filtercombo',
    /**
    * @cfg {string} recordField
    * @required
    * The fieldname of the record that contains the filtervalue
    */

    /**
    * @cfg {string} searchField
    * @required
    * The fieldname on which the filter should be applied
    */

    /**
    * @cfg {boolean} clearable
    * Indicates if the clear trigger should be hidden. Defaults to <tt>true</tt>.
    */
    clearable: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        if (me.clearable)
            me.trigger2Cls = 'x-form-clear-trigger';
        else
            delete me.onTrigger2Click;

        me.addEvents(

            /**
            * @event clear
            *
            * @param {Ext.ux.form.field.FilterCombo} FilterCombo The filtercombo that triggered the event
            */
            'clear',
            /**
            * @event beforefilter
            *
            * @param {Ext.ux.form.field.FilterCombo} FilterCombo The filtercombo that triggered the event
            * @param {String/Number/Boolean/Float/Date} value The value to filter by
            * @param {string} field The field to filter on
            */
            'beforefilter'
        );

        me.callParent(arguments);
        // fetch the id the save way
        var ident = me.getId();

        me.on('select', function (me, rec) {
            var value = rec[0].data[me.recordField],
                field = me.searchField;
            me.fireEvent('beforefilter', me, value, field)
            me.onShowClearTrigger(true); 
            me.onSearch(value, field);
        }, me);
        me.on('afterrender', function () { me.onShowClearTrigger(); }, me);
    },

    /**
    * @abstract onSearch
    * running a search on the store that may be removed separately
    * @param {String/Number/Boolean/Float/Date} val The value to search for
    * @param {String} field The name of the Field to search on
    */
    onSearch: Ext.emptyFn,

    /**
    * @abstract onFilterRemove
    * removing filters from the the
    * @param {Boolean} silent Identifies if the filter should be removed without reloading the store
    */
    onClear: Ext.emptyFn,

    onShowClearTrigger: function (show) {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.clearable)
            return;
        show = (Ext.isBoolean(show)) ? show : false;
        if (show) {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.setWidth(el.originWidth, false);
                    el.setVisible(true);
                    me.active = true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.originWidth = el.getWidth();
                    el.setWidth(0, false);
                    el.setVisible(false);
                    me.active = false;
                }
            });
        }
        // Version specific methods
        if (Ext.lastRegisteredVersion.shortVersion > 407) {
            me.updateLayout();
        } else {
            me.updateEditState();
        }
    },

    /**
    * @override onTrigger2Click
    * eventhandler
    */
    onTrigger2Click: function (args) {
        this.clear();
    },

    /**
    * @private clear
    * clears the current search
    */
    clear: function () {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.clearable)
            return;
        me.onClear(false);
        me.clearValue();
        me.onShowClearTrigger(false);
        me.fireEvent('clear', me);
    }
});
```

Here is an untested implementation of your combo. Please note that I cleaned up your `filterFn` but I didn't make any further check.

```
{
    xtype: 'filtercombo',
    id: 'iccombo',
    scope: this,
    store: this.Combostore,
    fieldLabel: 'Short State',
    displayField: 'States',
    valueField: 'States',   
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    name: 'State',
    labelWidth: 125,
    anchor: '95%',
    // begin new parts
    recordField: 'States',
    searchField: '',
    clearable: false,
    onSearch: function (me, value, field) {

        // New part!
        var store = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('YourStoreIdName');

        // Clear existing filters
        store.clearFilter(false);

        // Build filter
        var myfilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
        scope: this,
        filterFn: function (item) {
            var fieldNames = item.fields.keys,
                fieldName, stringVal,
                len = fieldNames.length,
                j = 0;

            for (; j < len; j++) {
                fieldName = fieldNames[j];
                if (item.data[fieldName] != null) {
                    stringVal = item.data[fieldName].toString();
                    if (stringVal != null && stringVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
        // Apply filter to store
        store.filter(myfilter);
    }
}
```

I guess this should work too

```
var myfilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
            scope: this,
            filterFn: function (rec) {
                var fieldValue = rec[this.fieldName];
                if (fieldValue && fieldValue === this.value)
                      return true;
            return false;
            }
        });
```

I set `this` before two vars to mark them as from a external scope.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed info sra... I am trying to implement your answer... whare do I declare me... is it the same as my scope: this... the reason I have used scope: this is that I have declare my store as this.myStore...

Comment: Thanks sra...  I hope they are not typos.. :)... is the for loop missing a declaration?

Comment: I can actually get inside the filterFn but nothing happens... no errors but blank grid.. what I noticed was ... my console print says store is undefined... I have a feeling the selected value is not being passed correctly

Comment: yes... I changed it to match my storename... I also checked to see if the value is being passed and it prints the selected value.... this.selectedC = value.getValue();...
        console.log('selectedValue: ' + this.selectedC);... also i did a consoleprint on return false... and it's printing false..

Comment: M almost there sra... i got to the last part of the search if statement where it says...TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: @eaglefox value will already be a primitive type. To be precisely; it will be the value of the record field, whatever that is. Are you sure that your filterFn works as expected? Be carful with the use of this! Whole using xtypes you normally never use this. This may also gives you troubles like that vars are undefined.

Comment: @EagleFox
ok, you need to save a copy of the value variable to the filterFn and use that from then on. I guess that should work. The problem is, the filterFn has a wrong scope and therefore value will be undefined I guess.

Comment: Sweeeeet sra... it's actually working... I am not sure but i took off this part ".indexOf(value.toLowerCase())" and now it works... :)... thanks man... I am gonna mark this as answer but please let me know what are the drawback of me removing that part... awesome!!!

Comment: @EagleFox Well, I guess they are huge! As I wrote in my last comment there is a scope problem which need to be resolved. Can you tell me, for what you are filtering. It looks like you took all records where in not a single field the value of the selection (combo) can be found. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes right now... the filter look for all the data in the store... right now combobox only filter "states'... so once it find TX, it filters that... also I inserted another if statement to complete the filter.... if (selectedC == stringVal).. which returns true and applies the filter... selectedC is the value selected from combobox which is 'states'

Answer (score 1):

i see 2 issues

1. store should have `remoteFilter: true` set
2. in JavaScript all variables declarations are picked out and hoisted to the beginning of the function. so any variables declared inside a loop should be taken out and declared at the top of the function. JS has no block scope (like Java).

Comment: Thanks for your pointers dbrin... I tried remoteFilter and it still didn't work back then... will definitely declare my variables globallyl

Comment: no no, not globally! you want to declare your variable at the top of the function (function scoped!) - that way you avoid mistakes in the loop. Remember that variables survive the loop end - not like in Java.

Comment: oooooh ok... that's what you were talking about... yes.. actually with sra's help, i was able to do just that... thanks